# Exclude one Data frame in list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm clubbing all the data frames into list using the below code.

`dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))`

but want to exclude one data frame getting into the list.

like out of 10 Data frames i need 9 to be added to the list and one need to excluded

Comment: Is the 1 left out `data.frame` a different `dim`? different `names`?  You'll need someway to identify it to programmatically exclude it.

Comment: @AdamSpannbauer The `data.frame` that needs to be eliminated has default name.`dim` will high always for the `data.frame` that need to eliminated

Comment: @Sotos this works for me. Please add it as answer....Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to do it in two steps

1 Create the list

2 Remove the data frame called (say) `df`

```
dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))
dflist[!names(dflist) %in% 'df']
```